# Content offset in scrollview

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6, scrollview

I have created my own `UITabBar` and I'm changing the views with

```
     [self transitionFromViewController: oldC toViewController: newC
                        duration: 0.1 options:0
                        animations:^{
                            newC.view.frame = oldC.view.frame;
                        }
                        completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                            [oldC removeFromParentViewController];
                            [newC didMoveToParentViewController:self];
                        }];
```

This app is working in iOS 7 and 6. In iOS 7 is working great.

But in iOS 6 when I have a `UIScrollView` the view controller, if I scroll down to the bottom and I change the tab and I come back again the `UIScrollView` shows a extra gap in the bottom:

[image]

I know the problem is that all the views have been moved up, because their frames are changed. But the content offset and inset are the right ones and the content size in the scrollview it's the same.

That happens in all view controller with `UIScrollView`, so it's not a `autolayout` problem, not at least in my rules.

Any idea what could I test?

Comment: What is automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets set to (it's not available on iOS 6 but on iOS 7 it's YES by default and will add content insets)

Comment: But the problem is in iOS 6, in iOS 7 is working well